# Is the traditional meaning of "strong AI" outmoded?

Tags: agi, terminology, history

Traditionally, "[strong AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_AI)" refers to [Artificial General Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence), the human mind understood as an algorithm ([Searle, Chinese Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room#Strong_AI)) and [Artificial Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_consciousness).

But recent advances in Artificial Intelligence, most notably breakthroughs involving Machine Learning and Neural Networks, have led to strong AI being used in the context of an algorithmic intelligence that can outperform the top humans in specific tasks.  (This is sometimes qualified as "strong narrow AI", but the qualifier seems less used time goes on.)

- Because the traditional usage of strong AI are based on theoretical concepts, where the current usage is based on practical, real-world results, does the new usage of "strong AI" supercede the traditional usage?

If this is the case, at what point does the Wiki need to be updated?  Is a major paper focused on re-coining the term necessary to formally reference the new usage of the term, or are numerous, informal uses sufficient?

---

Related: "Strong" has a precise, analytic, formal usage in the context of [solved games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game).  This game theoretic usage is similar in spirit to new usage of strong AI in that it connotes results that can be validated.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just stumbled upon it. Can you provide 1-2 links to sources that use the expression "strong AI" to refer to systems like AlphaGo and the expression "strong narrow AI"?

Comment: @nbro I'll do some google searches for references.  (I asked this question during the honeymoon period after Alpha Go when I saw the term starting to pop up.)

Comment: This "strong narrow AI" is marketing buzzword; we used to call them "weak AI", defined in your terms as "algorithmic intelligence that can outperform the top humans in specific tasks".

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of strong AI has changed as you correctly indicated, and the term "strong narrow AI" is more appropriate as now people are shifting towards the practical uses.
This also bring to light the number of breakthroughs that AI is having and literature and other various related resources will often(unlike in other fields) need to be changed constantly.